# How do you import a Razor page from a RCL you got from a NuGet package?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, nuget-package, razor-class-library

RCL stands for Razor class library.

I made my own prototype RCL with a Shared file _Layout.cshtml and I want to include it in my project. I already installed the RCL from NuGet hoping it would automagically work, but it apparently doesn't.

I deleted my _Layout.cshtml, hoping it would get taken from the RCL I made, but apparently that won't work like that. I get the following errors:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The layout view '_Layout' could not be located. The following locations were searched:
/Pages/_Layout.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.GetLayoutPage(ViewContext context, string executingFilePath, string layoutPath)
```

- How do I properly import this RCL into my new web app?

## Update

I added `@using libnamehere` to my _ViewImports.cshtml file and commented out the only line of code in `_ViewStart.cshtml` but now I get the following errors:

```
InvalidOperationException: RenderBody has not been called for the page at '/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml'. To ignore call IgnoreBody().

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.EnsureRenderedBodyOrSections()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> InvalidOperationException: RenderBody has not been called for the page
> at '/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml'. To ignore call IgnoreBody().
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.EnsureRenderedBodyOrSections()

By default, every layout must call `RenderBody`. Be sure add `@RenderBody()` in your `_Layout.cshtml`.

Reference:

[Layout in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-6.0#what-is-a-layout)

The whole working steps:

1.From Visual Studio select **Create new a new project**.

2.Select **Razor Class Library** > Click **Next**.

3.**Name the library** (for example, `RazorClassLib1`), > Click **Create**. To avoid a file name collision with the generated view library, ensure the library name doesn't end in .Views.

4.Select S**upport pages and views** >Select **Create**.

5.Add `_BaseTemplateLayout.cshtml` which located in `/Pages/Shared` in the `RazorClassLib1` project.

```
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <h1>Layout</h1>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
```

6.Add a new Razor View Start file to the `Pages` folder in the `RazorClassLib1` project named `_ViewStart.cshtml`. The default template should contain the following code:

```
@{
    Layout = "_BaseTemplateLayout";
}
```

Project Structure:

[image]

7.Run the pack command in `RazorClassLib1` project:

> dotnet pack

Get the result:
[image]

8.Create a Mvc/Razor pages Project called `TestProject1`.

9.We need to go into the target projects(`TestProject1`) .csproj file. Here we point out both the path to our local NuGet package and the NuGet stream. It should look like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RestoreSources>$(RestoreSources);absolute-path-to-my-solution/bin/Debug;https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json</RestoreSources>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You need to replace `absolute-path-to-my-solution/bin/Debug` above with the absolute path to where your package is located. When you run pack command you can get the successfull result with the location(Step 7).

10.Install the nuget package in `TestProject1` project with command(`dotnet add [<PROJECT>] package <PACKAGE_NAME>`):

```
dotnet add TestProject1 package RazorClassLib1
```

11.Be sure add razor pages support in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddRazorPages();
```

12.Change your _ViewStart.cshtml in `TestProject1` project:

```
@{
    Layout = "_BaseTemplateLayout";
}
```

Comment: My `_Layout.cshtml` in the RCL contains `RenderBody()`...

Comment: Actually this error indicates no `RenderBody()`, please check it in `/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` and explain more for your project structure.

Comment: There is no `_Layout.cshtml` in the new project, only in the RCL. Also I was technically incorrect about my changes in the new project, sorry for that, let me fix the question.

Comment: Just for confirmation. Your RCL contains _Layout.cshtml and you want to apply this Layout to another asp.net core project. And your asp.net core project does not have _Layout.cshtml and remove ` Layout = "_Layout";` in `_ViewStart.cshtml`. So you just apply Layout in view/page(like Index.cshtml). Did you want to do like what I said?

Comment: Hi @Munchkin, please check my detailed updated answer.

Comment: the `_Layout.cshtml` should get used for the new project, exactly. I messed with the `_ViewStart.cshtml` only because of the errors and that was probably incorrect...

Comment: I'm afraid I did the very same thing, just that I specified _Layout, because that's the name of it as it's supposed to be called. I used the command "Pack" by clicking the project instead of the CLI commands, but it shouldn't matter

Comment: Maybe you need check the steps one by one and repack the RCL. Then used in another project. No need comment the line in `_ViewStart.cshtml`, on the contrary, you need specific the layout name which belongs to RCL  in `_ViewStart.cshtml`. What if you change the Layout name which is different from `_Layout`?

Comment: So in both the RCL's `_ViewStart.cshtml` and in the new project's `_ViewStart.cshtml` I tried changing the `_Layout` to `_Template` but it just throws me `InvalidOperationException: The layout view '_Template' could not be located.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240123/discussion-between-rena-and-munchkin).